# JQuery loop through childs and adds to another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML element which contains list of spans containing author text names, I need to place each span of author name to a list of li elements respectively how to do this using JQuery?

```
var all_author_names = $('.postcontent .entry_content #author-name'); // get list of spans containg names
var li_to_modifiy = $('.entry_meta > li:nth-child(3)') // gets list of li elements that I need to add each name respectively
```

**EDIT:**

Simplified HTML:

```
<div class="postcontent nobottommargin clearfix">
    <ul class="entry_meta clearfix">
      <li class="hide"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li><span>|</span><a href="#"><i class="icon-link"></i>Permalink</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="page-divider"><span></span></span>
    <div class="entry_content"> 
       <p></p><div class="entry_image">
       <span id="author-name" class="hide">Karen Hutchins</span>
  </div>
</div>

 </div>
```

NOTE: The postcontent class is auto generated and I have a lot of it, not only one.

To make things clear:

1- let all_author_names contains this html:

```
<span>my name</span>
<span>other name</span>
<span>your name</span>
```

2- I need each li element inside the postcontent class to have one span relevant to its index, so the result would be:

```
<div class="postcontent nobottommargin clearfix">
    <ul class="entry_meta clearfix">
      <li class="hide"></li>
      <li><span>my name</span></li>
```

Other postcontent class

```
<div class="postcontent nobottommargin clearfix">
    <ul class="entry_meta clearfix">
      <li class="hide"></li>
      <li> <span>other name</span></li>
```

Comment: question not so clear, better ya post code.

Comment: @Wazery to get the author name you can simply `$('#author-name').text()` if you do repeat #author-name better change it to class .author-name

Comment: Added extra explanation, hope this makes things clear for you Mar Cejas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But I guess, you wanted something like this:

```
var all_author_names = $('.postcontent .entry_content #author-name'); // get list of spans containg names
var li_to_modifiy = $('.entry_meta > li:nth-child(3)') // gets list of li elements that I need to add each name respectively

all_author_names.find('span').each(function(a,b){
 console.log(b.text());
});

li_to_modifiy.find('li').each(function(a,b){
 console.log(b.text());
});
```

**UPDATED ANSWER FROM YOUR UPDATED QUESTION:**

```
$('.postcontent').each(function(a,b){
    $(b).find('li:eq(1)').html('<span>'+$.trim($(b).find('#author-name').text())+'</span>');
    console.log($.trim($(b).text()));
});
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22B2J/1/)

Comment: Worked but give each li the same author name!.

Comment: Note that it worked only when changing the '.entry-meta > li:eq(2)' to '.entry_meta > li:nth-child(3)'

Comment: Still giving the same author name, and not working with li:eq(2) but did with li:nth-child(3). I gave it +1 though!

Comment: I edited the question with a missing line, the author-name id is inside a class entry_content.

Comment: @Wazery the solution will still work as long as #author-name inside the .postcontent

Comment: It was my fault, the wrapper class is .entry not .postcontent :) sorry for that.